# Having trouble with setting up an array in PHP and write MySQL values to it

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
          session_start(); 
        }
        $userid = $row['userid'];
        $_SESSION = array(
                      'login' => true,
                      'user'  => array(
                          'username'  => ['username'],
                          'userid' => $userid
                         ),
           'favshow' => array(
              '0' => $userid
           ),
           'fav' => array(
              '0' => '1'
           ), 
                    );
                    // $_SESSION['user']['favshow'] = array();

        // Load Favorites in Session
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE userid =" . $userid ."";
        $result2=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
          if($row['show']){
           $_SESSION['user']['favshow'][] = $row['clubid'];
          }else{
            $_SESSION['user']['fav'][] = $row['clubid'];
```

Hey, I´m currently trying to initialize the 'fav' and 'showfav' arrays in the $_SESSION['user'] but with no success. This is a part of my login script, so when a user logs in the favorites from the table should be added to their session. It currently says that there is no such index as #fav' and 'favshow' and I do not know why. Am I getting anything wrong with the syntax? I tried a bunch of different styles, still no success...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: var_dump($_Session), whats in it?

Comment: array(2) { ["login"]=> bool(true) ["user"]=> array(2) { ["username"]=> NULL ["userid"]=> string(1) "2" } }

Comment: im changing to prepared statements once all the stuff works :) had some trouble with it

Comment: There's no fav index in there....

Comment: Thats the problem, sorry if I was unclear in the post. As 'favshow' is similar to the userid it should have the value 2, but somehow it doesn´t want to add it

Comment: You have declared $_SESSION to be an array, with a user subscript. However the fav and favshow subscripts are directly part of $_SESSION, not under the user subscript. Remove the bracket before favshow and place it at the end of the declare.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D feeling stupid now

Answer (score 0):

Think you are trying to set an array element that doesn't exist. It exists within the $_SESSION array rather than the $_SESSION['user'] array.

Try it like this, with the initialisation moved:-

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
$userid = $row['userid'];
$_SESSION = array(
                'login' => true,
                'user'  => array(
                    'username'  => ['username'],
                    'userid' => $userid,
                    'favshow' => array('0' => $userid),
                    'fav' => array('0' => '1') 
                                )
                );
            // $_SESSION['user']['favshow'] = array();

// Load Favorites in Session
$sql = "SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE userid =" . $userid ."";
$result2=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    if($row['show'])
    {
        $_SESSION['user']['favshow'][] = $row['clubid'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user']['fav'][] = $row['clubid'];
    }
}
```

I would also be a bit careful about just using the whole session variable as a single array for this. I would be inclined to add any variable / array I wanted to store in the session as a subscript to the session. Otherwise in future you will want to store something else in the $_SESSION array and it will be over written by this script.